# Curve Programmatically Calculated?

Tags: performance, actionscript-3, math, curve

How can I calculate `y` in this curve ? `t` is the variable. Origin is `(0|0)` of course.

- the tangents at `t=0`, `t=0,5` and `t=1` must be perfectly horizontal (incline = 0)
- only basic mathematical operators are available (Java / Actionscript 3)

[image]

I have to calculate this a few hundred times each frame in Actionscript 3. So calculation needs good performance. Right now I'm actually **failing at correctness** of calculation (I'm not a mathematician).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure about performance, but

`-0.5 * cos(x * 2pi) + 0.5`

AS3:

```
y = -0.5 * Math.cos(x * 2 * Math.PI) + 0.5;
```

seems to be the curve you are looking for.

[image]

You can view or edit the curve here:
[wolfram alfa curve](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-0.5*cos%28x*2pi%29+%2B+0.5+from+0+to+1)

Comment: +1 nice answer, one little thing: cos() in AS3 is Math.cos() and it takes radians in parameter

Comment: Thanks san.chez, i added the AS3 info

Answer (score 4):

The function suggested by bjornson (`-0.5*cos(x) + 0.5`) looks good.

One idea to improve performance is that you at the start of your application create a table of the values of that function at different times.

If you use fix timesteps, then the table is all you'll need. If you have variable time steps, then you can just do linear interpolation between the two closest times to the time you're calculating.

Answer (score 2):

```
y(t) = 16 * t * t * (t - 1) * (t - 1)
```

I reckon that one satisfies your requirements

Answer (score 0):

I tried my own way and I came up with a [polynomial](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=16%28x-0.5%29%5E4%20-%208%28x-0.5%29%5E2%20%2b%201%20from%200%20to%201):

```
y = 16 * (t - 0.5)^4 - 8 * (t - 0.5)^2 + 1
y = 16 * Math.pow((t - 0.5), 4) - 8 * Math.pow((t - 0.5), 2) + 1;
// forgot to shift the curve 0.5 to the right, corrected
```

Comment: Just out of interest. You said that dmuir was incorrect: http://tinyurl.com/pxrth86 Why are you more correct? Your curve is identical: http://tinyurl.com/oxu7z2v

Comment: Not sure why it looks right on wolframalpha but it didn't have the expected behavior as other functions. In my AS-3 app it is transfered into animation.